# How to filter using any of the full text queries?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've tried numerous ways to filter using a full text query, but to no avail.
Here's what I've attempted:

```
{
    "_source": "_id",
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "test search query",
                "fields": ["title"]
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": {"user_id": "1"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`filtered` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) takes a `filter` and a `query`, you're missing a `query` part which wraps your `multi_match`:

```
{
    "_source": "_id",
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {               <-- add this
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "test search query",
                    "fields": ["title"]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": {"user_id": "1"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```